# Handoff measuring

Tags: ios, swift

I want to measure in analytics usage of Handoff in my app. How to check that NSUserActivity comes from handoff? 
Variable eligableforhandoff doesn't work, because it is true after spotlightsearch too

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `userInfo` dictionary on the activity to pass any app-specific information you want (if it can be encoded into a plist). So you can specify some key that you only add for handoff and use that to track any details you want.

Comment: I thought about it. It doesn't work because I have the same NSUserActivity for SpotlightSearch too. I have handoff between web and mobile app

Comment: you don't have to use the same instances, you can have one instance that's setup for handoff and another for search publishing that both reference the same content

Comment: I know about it, but you have to have two NSUserActivity because of analytics - it's bad approach.

Comment: define bad - they're 2 different representations of the same thing used for different purposes. i'm not a big fan of adding stuff just for analytics but you do have 2 different situations to deal with...